# Cloning Linux and Windows from two separate disks to a single SSD

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, ssd, grub

**Backstory TL;DR:** cloned OpenSUSE from `/dev/sda2` to `/dev/sdc1`, Windows 7 from `/dev/sdb1` to `/dev/sdc2`; formatted `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb1`; reconfigured GRUB2 and installed it on `/dev/sdc`; OpenSUSE loads, Windows 7 doesn't.

**Backstory (long):** A couple days back I've cloned two systems from separate drives to a single SSD. Let's assume that there was OpenSUSE on `/dev/sda2` and Windows 7 on `/dev/sdb1`, dual-booted with GRUB2 installed in `/dev/sda`'s MBR.

The cloning itself was done with Clonezilla's part-to-part method, SUSE went to the newly created `/dev/sdc1` and W7 to `/dev/sdc2`. GRUB2 was updated from a Mint liveusb (in a nutshell, `chroot`ing into a mounted root of a cloned system with `/sys /dev /proc` and `/run` from liveusb's root `mount --bind`'ed onto cloned root).

First problem (kinda solved): `grub2-mkconfig` found the systems (two SUSEs and two W7s), updated itself and was grub2-install'ed on /dev/sdc. However, regardless of which hard drive I booted from and what option chose, OpenSUSE only loaded from the old drive (with specific cracking of an old IDE drive and adequate loading time). Of the Windowses the one on the old drive booted okay (though that sort of defeated the purpose of migration), the second didn't boot at all (blinking cursor on black screen).

After some testing I figured that when `/dev/sda` is unplugged physically, grub loads OpenSUSE from the SSD just fine. Next, with a stroke of genius, I formatted the old `/dev/sda2` partition where OpenSUSE used to be. And `/dev/sdb1`, where W7 used to be (for whatever reason).

**Outcome:** OpenSUSE loads as it should. W7 does not.

**Problems with restoring Windows:**

1. Windows repair disk (downloaded from Microsoft's site) doesn't recognize cloned Windows on the SSD. I assume Windows 7 Recovery disk doesn't take too kindly to SSDs in general.
2. Windows won't let me install it on the second partition (technically, on NOT FIRST partition).

**Question:**
I assume there was some sort of PBR (partition boot record) on the old Windows partition (that's what GRUB2 chainloads, if I understand it correctly). How come clonezilla didn't copy it along with the rest of partition? And if it did, why doesn't it boot now, even with GRUB having this partition in its cfg?

And if it was not a PBR, but MBR, can it somehow be copied and adjusted to let the Windows on the second partition boot?

Is there any way at all to have a W7 installation booting from the second partition on the SSD?

Comment: You will have to explain PBR my research found nothing relevant

Comment: Edited the question. What I meant was 'partition boot record'. As far as I understand, Windows 7 does create this record (however I'm not sure under what circumstances it does or doesn't), and from what I've read on the forums/microsoft support teh windows recovery disk can restore either MBR of PBR (or both). Well, at least it should.